# Complete stranger asking PhD student to review paper before submission

Tags: publications, peer-review, academic-life

I am a PhD student and I have been contacted today by some other PhD student with a very odd request. He is from a different university in a different country and I don't know him at all. He is asking me to review his own paper before submitting it to some journal. Is this a common thing to ask? What is the best response in this case?

Comment: "He is asking me to review his own paper" - is it just that, or is he providing some explanation as to why he has picked you of all people for exactly this paper of his? This could provide some insight into whether it's a case as described in [Dave's answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/76479/14017), or one facet of [mostly undirected academic spam](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41687/what-is-behind-the-indian-undergrad-research-experience-spam/41723).

Comment: Part of the job as a phd is to make as many contacts as possible in many different places: so congratulations, you just gained one for free :)... don't waste it.

Comment: I find the etiquette about these things can be very different from one area of research to an other. I would ask my advisor and/or fellow phd students within your field.

Comment: papers are included or not in to email. Do you have published works, by your self or here you one of authors. If papers included are they correlated to your field of work. Why to not write "not interested" if you are not and ignore if this is a scam.

Answer (score 16):

I'm not surprised to hear this.  I often encourage my students to reach out to others working in their specific field.  Do it if you have the time, interest, and expertise.  Ignore it if you don't.  Don't think there's more to it than that.

Comment: Isn't it a bit weird to reach out to another PhD student though? I don't have an academic background, but this seems weird to me. Or is it simply because another student is good enough and likely has more free time than a graduate?

Comment: Sounds like a nice plan and might end up in a collaboration or "professional friendship". But in that case this should be reasonably well explained in the mail. As in "I know you don't know me, but I like your work and do similar stuff, so what do you think about helping each other out?"

Comment: @skymningen is that similar field or same field - can be seen from paper, less then 30sec to judge.

Comment: @Kevin not sure what's so weird about it.  A lot of academia is collaboration.  In theory, anyway.

Answer (score 15):

If he's a complete stranger, I can understand the situation feeling a little creepy to you.

I suggest you ask him how he chose you for this role.  Ask him where he's studying and who his advisor is.  Look up the advisor online to see if everything looks above-board.

His response to a short email with a couple of neutrally posed questions may help you figure out if you are comfortable with his initiative.

Comment: But see that's just the thing...why all the back-and-forth?  If you want to do it and you think it could be useful, do it!  If you couldn't care less or think there's some bad mojo behind the request then ignore it and move on.  I certainly don't pay attention to or act on every e-mail that comes to my inbox or call or piece of mail that comes to my house.  There's not some magic equation that's suddenly involved because this other person purports to be a PhD student.

Comment: @DaveKaye - Agreed, a lot of back-and-forth would not be worthwhile.  Very good point.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't know him at all, it can be a little weird, but the ice can be broken if you exchange some e-mails. As others have said, you can be more comfortable with him if you talk more. Also, you can ask if you two can collaborate on a project. You didn't give any details on the particular paper, if it seems a good idea, and also his publication record. If the paper seems good(even if it is not perfectly written yet), IMHO you can start a collaboration.

Answer (score 1):

From a social and scientific standpoint, you should agree if you have time and interest in the paper. You may get a contact who works on similar themes and you may collaborate in the future. As others have noted, the person will also likely be on the hook for reading one of your future manuscripts as well.

There is, however, another perspective, which is that of someone who is concerned about intellectual property. Many large companies have strict "no unsolicited ideas"-policies, because they do not want to risk future disputes. Something similar may apply to you: Say you are already working on a new method for solving problem X, that you have not currently published. You recieve a paper from a stranger who has had the same idea. Suddently, by accepting the manuscript, you may in the future be accused on plagiarism of the same idea. The reasonable thing would perhaps be to collaborate on a joint paper since you have the same idea, but people in the academic sector are *not always reasonable*.

This depends highly on the nature of your field of research. In my experience, these types of issues are likely more prevailent for research with commercial applications. Universities are increasingly becoming concerned about intellectual property rights as well.

Answer (score 0):

Barring the less-likely (and nefarious) reasons (he wants to make contact with you for some other reason, he is spamming all phds at your university) such request is perfectly legitimate.

You did not say if the paper is from your area of research, or whether he refers to some of your published work - that may be important in determining the reason why he is asking you for review.

Actually, checking the quality of one's paper with your peers (other phd students) is a very common advice given to phd students by their supervisors (if they are any good). True, this mainly refers to the other people in a lab, but there is no reason that people would not go beyond this.

What does he gain by you doing the review? Well, if you will criticize his paper, he can fix the problems and has better chance to be accepted first time around or with minor revision. The reasoning is, even if you are only phd student, if you can find problems with his paper, the more experienced reviewers will find them too (and probably some additional problems you will probably miss). It is not called "peer review" for nothing (check the definition of the "peer" in the dictionary).

What do you gain by honoring his request (although, I should stress, you are in no way **obliged** to do the review, especially if it is far from your own area of research!)? Well, first, you will get insight into what your peers (your competition perhaps) are doing. You may get a invaluable chance to peek into the good paper which will be officially published in 6 months or even longer (although, until it is published, you will be bound by the confidentiality). Yes, you may find out that the paper is worthless and that it was all waste of time, but hey, welcome to academia and the world of peer reviews. It will not be your last time.

So, I would suggest, that you ask him why he contacted specifically you. If he is following your publications, then perhaps you will be interested in what he is doing. If you find out that his research is unrelated, politely decline and say that you are not expert in his area.