# Should I call professors on their office phone for inquiring about research internship opportunities?

Tags: etiquette, research-undergraduate, internship

There are many established university research internship program, which ask to get an acceptance from a faculty to apply for the internship. I tried mailing them, but none of them responded. Should I call them over phone to ask about any opportunity? At least that would help me know where I am lacking so that I can prepare myself for the internship the next year. But I'm not sure if the researchers would view it favorably.

Comment: Speaking only for myself (UK academic): no, this should not be done, if the "target" has not previously responded by email.

Comment: @YemonChoi Umm, then what other way is there to know what skills I am lacking? Neither am I being able to contact the researchers whose research I'm interested in via mail nor being able to call them in the fear of being viewed as desperate/rude. I don't even know if the professors/researchers have even read my mail.

Comment: Professors are people too. They may have other duties to tend to. Give it time, and don't push the subject.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I'm not really pushing. I just sent one email to each one of them. It's been around 2 weeks now. Should I try my luck by mailing some other professors?

Comment: Nobody gives feedback, unless it is mandatory (article reviews/etc), get used to it. Especially in selection processes, when giving feedback would leave them open to get sued....

Comment: @FábioDias What do you mean by "leave them open to get sued" ?

Comment: @Blue: The more you explain, the more likely it is you say something that can be used legally against you. Sadly, just rejecting someone without providing any explanation is encouraged by legal frameworks as it is the legally safest way for the one doing the selection (among applicants for a job, a flat, ...).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ah, I see. Thanks for explaining. :)  These things are complicated.

Comment: @blue, could you clarify a bit better what you are talking about? Are these at a university at which you are a student? Are you a student in another university looking for a summer job in a research group elsewhere? Are these publicly advertised (say a particular funding agency gives money to support faculty to hire outside students for a research opportunity)? I don't have a clue about the what you mean by 'well established university internship programs' as I've never heard of anything that would correspond in the US.

Comment: Is this related to https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41687/what-is-behind-the-indian-undergrad-research-experience-spam ?

Comment: @Carol I'm referring to the Indian universities (for example IISc, Bangalore) which take in summer research interns. Say, I'm from a different university. Many a times they mention on their website notice that students can contact the professors for **internship/VS** program. If the professors are willing to accept the students for their project, then the university provides the visiting student/intern with accommodation and travel expenses to enable to work under the professor's guidance in a research project.

Comment: @Carol Also, many institutes like RRI, PRL, TIFR have such visiting student's program. Yes, some of the programs do have a separate portal for application but at the same time many of them accept student interns only if a particular professor from the institute is willing to take them. Basically there are two ways of applying for an internship: 1) Apply through the application portal which is opened for a short span of time on each  institute's portal 2) Contact professors directly for internship positions. My query is about 2.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What's an "office phone"?

We used to have these white (sometimes black) boxes with buttons on them many years ago, but the last round of budget cuts took them away. I don't think many people noticed their disappearance.

On a more serious note, you're sounding a bit like a stalker or an annoying salesperson. If the emails aren't being answered (you should send one follow up after the initial one, but no more than two total), take that as a strong NO**. Phoning the professor is only going to annoy them.

---

** You didn't ask, but reasons for the NO:

1. I have no internships.
2. I have internships but they've all been allocated.
3. I have internships but they're restricted to our undergraduates or to local high school students who are in the internship program.
4. A quick scan of whatever you sent me makes it clear you're inappropriate (you can't spell, you just graduated high school, you have no background in the field, our internships are restricted to particular categories of enrolled students, etc.).  However, HR told us to never say 'no' in terms of justifications that could open us up to lawsuits, so it's best to just ignore.
5. Internships are handled through a committee or other open process that if you did some googling you could easily find.  And I really have no use for an intern who can't find things by themselves.

As to why I don't send a 'no': I have five grant proposals, an external tenure review, two journal reviews, and my own research papers to write. Writing a polite no takes more time than a simple 'no' and again opens me / my university up to a lawsuit. Finally, answering what is essentially spam e-mail is my lowest priority.

If you are going to phone anyone, phone the department front office, university HR, or university student services or career services program (assuming you're an enrolled student). Be prepared for a 'no' answer and don't badger.

Comment: By "office phone" I mean the telephone which is assigned to each professor in their office (the phone numbers are usually found on their personal websites). BTW thank your for the answer.

Comment: Ours used to be black, but we completely switched to mobile phones three years ago. I completely agree: I wouldn't appreciate such calls at all. In fact, the only work-related calls I get are either from people I know well or from journalists. If we don't have a previous relationship, email me.

Comment: Do you really not have an office phone anymore?

Comment: No. When we moved to a new building, they gave mobile phones to everyone (from PhD student to full professor) and didn't bother to install landlines. I guess no-one misses them. Only exception are some support staff offices (e.g., for incoming calls from students).

Comment: My university started charging US$30 a line per month. Our department decided that while $360/year per faculty didn't sound that bad, when you have 25 faculty, that came in aggregate to $9,000 a year for a resource that wasn't being used much. If you only make 2-3 calls a month on a landline, each phone call is $10+!!

Comment: _"HR told us to never say 'no' in terms of justifications that could open us up to lawsuits, so it's best to just ignore"_ is just sad, if it's true.

Comment: +1 "sounding a bit like a stalker or an annoying salesperson"  Professors already get reams of unsolicited emails; if they start getting such phone calls on their office phones, maybe they really WILL get rid of their phones.