# Department of Engineering does this my research plan for MSc falls?

Tags: graduate-admissions, engineering, canada, electrical-engineering

I have written to so many professors to be my supervisor for fall 2022 in a research plan that involves design and construction of a power converter for a new charging system for Multirotor Unmanned Aerial Vehicle. The new charging system is gotten from the idea of free energy generator using neodymium magnets and external coils. The neodymium magnets of small size and weight are glued to the propeller and turns of coil around the propeller. So when the UAV propeller is rotating it's also generating emf to power the payloads. When the rotation speed is slow, the Lithium Polymer battery takes control. Is this research proposal not researchable? I have sent email to professors in Canadian universities about it. They don't respond. Under what Engineering Department can I apply to? Aerospace engineering or Power electronics Engineering?

Comment: In which department are the professors you already emailed? Assuming you emailed them after having looked at their research a little bit and checking whether it matches with your ideas, of course.

Comment: To add to that, engineering graduate admissions in Canada — like the US — are handled at a departmental level, and emailing professors will not improve your chances of admission. It may help you if you're admitted though.

Comment: They are in electrical and computer engineering. I checked their publication before emailing them. They specialize in power electronics

Comment: Then apply to that department.

Comment: They are not into UAV but power electronics. Can I still apply?

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty is that in graduate school you seldom work on what you want, but you work instead on what your advisor will let you work on.  The two do not always coincide.  In other words, professors take students to work on the areas where they (the professors) have expertise, not in areas where students would like to work.

Next, be aware that professors receive a lot of “cold call” emails from student so unless your letter is very well crafted it will be ignored.  See for instance [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/173122/90441) on tips to write a good letter.

In particular, poorly researched generic letters are easy to spot and routinely ignored.

So I would suggest first you consider changing your strategy in presenting yourself as a prospective student, and next consider re-sending more personalized letters showing interest in the research program of professors.
If your original emails were binned, it’s unlikely you will be remembered if you ask again in a different way.  Third, feel free to expand your reach, but always in a personalized manner.

Finally, be reminded that the simplest way to get admitted to a graduate program is to send in a application: many professors will not commit to anything until they have seen the full application file.  You can indicate in a cover letter or at some later time that you’re interested in this or that topic, or in the research area of this or that professor.