# Is it polite to send another reminder to your ex-supervisor after they confirmed availablity of a vacancy?

Tags: etiquette, job-search, email, research-assistantship

I reached out to my ex-supervisor regarding the availability of a RA in their group about 2 months ago, via mail. The email exchange we have had till now has been at 2:1; where I send a reply followed by a follow-up/reminder mail after 3-4 weeks. We have had 2 exchanges till now. In our last conversation through mail, the Prof told me about the availability of a position which is of my interest. They said that the description of the role will become clearer in a week. I replied right away, showing my keen interest in that position.

Now, it has been over 2 weeks since the time the vacancy's description would have been defined; as per the Prof. I am wondering if I should send another mail asking about the specifics of the role and how I can apply to the position. Would it be rude to send another mail because up until now I have only received a reply after sending a follow-up/reminder mail? I am in a dilemma, since it is a really interesting project to work on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get people to reply to emails and what to make of a no response?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/45616/how-to-get-people-to-reply-to-emails-and-what-to-make-of-a-no-response)

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/173122/is-this-way-of-writing-e-mails-to-professors-asking-for-funded-phd-positions-to

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9542/is-ignoring-emails-acceptable-in-academia

Comment: @Sursula-they- Thanks for tagging the question, but it doesn't really answer and mine is more circumstantial here; that's why I posted a separate question here.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the field, culture, and the specific communication you have with your professor. You indicate an excessively submissive stance; however, some disciplines and cultures are prone to more authoritarian structures than others, so you would know best yourself how to "feel it out" in your particular case. One option might be to take a detour and preface your renewed request by bringing up some topic in which you have a common interest, eg something from your past cooperation? Good luck.